# Как можно вывести связанные записи в одной таблице в MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица со списком задач

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице есть поля с ссылками на предыдущую (link_pred_uid) и на последующую (link_succ_uid) задачи.
Как можно вывести список всех связанных задач по входящему параметру task_uid (к сожалению task_uid  и link_uid имеют разные значения), т.е. если на вход идет параметр task_uid = 11, то вывести предыдущую, текущую и последующую задачи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Upd:

```
USE [db]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dependence](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [task_uid] [int] NULL,
    [link_pred_uid] [int] NULL,
    [link_uid] [int] NULL,
    [link_succ_uid] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dependence] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[dependence]
           ([name]
           ,[task_uid]
           ,[link_pred_uid]
           ,[link_uid]
           ,[link_succ_uid])
     VALUES
           ('покраска'
           ,10
           ,4
           ,2
           ,2)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[dependence]
           ([name]
           ,[task_uid]
           ,[link_pred_uid]
           ,[link_uid]
           ,[link_succ_uid])
     VALUES
           ('купить краску'
           ,11
           ,6
           ,4
           ,2)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[dependence]
           ([name]
           ,[task_uid]
           ,[link_pred_uid]
           ,[link_uid]
           ,[link_succ_uid])
     VALUES
           ('построить забор'
           ,12
           ,6
           ,6
           ,4)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[dependence]
           ([name]
           ,[task_uid]
           ,[link_pred_uid]
           ,[link_uid]
           ,[link_succ_uid])
     VALUES
           ('сварка'
           ,13
           ,10
           ,8
           ,8)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[dependence]
           ([name]
           ,[task_uid]
           ,[link_pred_uid]
           ,[link_uid]
           ,[link_succ_uid])
     VALUES
           ('купить трубу'
           ,14
           ,10
           ,10
           ,8)
```

при WHERE task_uid = 11, то результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при WHERE task_uid = 13, то
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть от заданной задачи надо плясать в обе стороны, выбирая всё дерево задач, которое включает указанную задачу? Тогда просто стройте полные характеристические пути для каждой задачи, а потом выбирайте нужные по подстроке.

Comment: PS. Замените фотографии на текстовые CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц, дайте тестовое наполнение в формате INSERT INTO (дерево должно быть полным, по логике смысла данных должны существовать первые и последние задачи - или у таковых сама задача является своим предком/потомком?), и покажите пару комплектов (исходное task_uid - требуемый результат).

Comment: Внес изменения как Вы просили

Comment: Крайне странно, что при отсутствии предыдущей/следующей задачи ставится собственный ID, а не NULL

Comment: См. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f894cb793392de17b26aba47bac22a38). Доделывайте - конвертируйте task_uid в link_uid и выбирайте записи, где он присутствует в path. Мне уже этот беспомощный SQL server с его "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column" поперёк горла.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов это не принципиально, возможен вариант и с NULL, просто пример такой привел

Comment: Предыдущие задачи нужны все, рекурсивно, или только одна ?

Comment: @Mike все, и предыдущие и последующие (если таковые имеются)

Answer (score 1):

```
with CTE as(
    select *, 3 updown from dependence where task_uid=11
  union all
    select d.*, case when d.link_uid = c.link_pred_uid then 1 else 2 end
      from CTE c, dependence d
     where (c.link_uid!=c.link_pred_uid and d.link_uid = c.link_pred_uid and c.updown & 1 != 0)
        or (c.link_uid!=c.link_succ_uid and d.link_uid = c.link_succ_uid and c.updown & 2 != 0)
)
select * from CTE
```

В общем то обычный рекурсивный CTE. Единственное нестандартное решение - указание разрешенного направления движения по ссылкам в битовом поле updown. 1 - вверх (к родителю), 2 - вниз.

Вообще структура таблицы оставляет желать лучшего. Установка полей link_pred_uid в то же значение что link_uid потенциально могла бы приводить к рекурсии в подобных запросах и это всегда надо учитывать (условие c.link_uid!=c.link_pred_uid). Лучше было бы ставить значение NULL в конце цепочки. Кроме того двусторонняя связь требует особого внимания и потенциально может оказаться не корректной. Например дочерняя запись указанная в succ будет указывать на другого родителя в pred. Это обязывает любые записи менять парами в пределах одной транзакции и лучше бы контролировать триггерами. Любые нарушения ссылок в БД скорее всего будут приводить данный запрос к аварийному завершению в связи с зацикливанием.

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c2be5/1)

Comment: `c.link_uid!=c.link_pred_uid and d.link_uid = c.link_pred_uid` можно заменить на `d.link_uid = NULLIF(c.link_pred_uid, c.link_uid)`

Answer (score 0):

Общий алгоритм такой:

1. По `task_uid` найти строку, вывести ее, запомнить `link_pred_uid` и `link_succ_uid`
2. Найти соседей

   - Найти предка по `link_pred_uid`, 
      если есть - вывести, запомнить его `link_pred_uid`, 
      если нету - обнулить `link_pred_uid`.
   - Найти потомка по `link_succ_uid`,  
      если есть - вывести, запомнить его `link_succ_uid`,  
      если нету - обнулить `link_succ_uid`.
3. Повторять пункт 2, пока находится хотя бы один сосед.

Можно реализовать через рекурсивный запрос самосоединением (гуглить ключевые слова `WITH`, `CTE`)

Также можно сделать циклом в табличной функции.

По синтаксису не подскажу, MS SQL под рукой нету